# Setting a default in PHP button code

Tags: php, html, wordpress, button

I am trying to set a default button as selected in the following code:

```
<div class="accordion ui-group">
<h3><a href="#">Certification</a></h3>
<div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="certification" >
<button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">All</button>

<?php
    $term_id = 69;
    $taxonomy_name = 'project_category';
    $term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
    foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
        $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
        if( $term->count > 0 ) {
            echo '<button class="button" data-filter=".'. $term->slug .'">'. $term->name .'</button>';  
        };
    };
?>

</div>
</div>
```

The options are being populated with `Project Categories` with the parent of `Certifications` (`id=69`).

Right now, `ALL` is selected by default, but I want to specify a default to a specific option. I know this should be easy, but I cannot figure it out!

Any help would be great.

Comment: `data-filter` is an unusual attribute. I assume you're using jQuery Isotope? In that case, the solution is jQuery-driven, not PHP.

Comment: @DeniseH ***"Right now, «ALL» is selected by default, but I want to specify a default to a specific option."*** Would you want to elaborate on what you meant with **ALL**? Is it the All as in `<button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">All</button>` or ALL the generated Buttons? And what would qualify as Your ***specific*** Option?

Comment: sorry for being unclear.  and thank you all for the help so far!

Comment: The code above in my question generates this a list of buttons... ALL, plus four other options. All is currently the default and IS needed so that the user has the ability to filter back to ALL (or basically apply no filter).  I would like it to default to one of the 4 options below all.  The options that are listed below ALL on the page are PROJECT CATEGORIES that are nested under the main category of  CERTIFICATIONS.

Comment: being wordpress those project categories and sub categories all have an ID # so I think it should be fairly easy to set a specific ID number as the default. here is a link to the page http://coffeeholding.com/dev/specialty-green/ if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how $term->name was set up. I usually would use `empty($term->name) ? "Default" :  $term->name` where the button name should go.

If the name was never set, use `$term->name ?? "Default"` instead, for PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

The Code-Snippets below is fairly commented and thus Self-Explanatory... You might want to give it a go...

```
<div class="accordion ui-group">
    <h3><a href="#">Certification</a></h3>
    <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group" data-filter-group="certification" >
        <!-- THIS BUTTON IS OUTSIDE THE LOOP AND HAS THE CLASS: is-checked -->
        <!-- CLEARLY, ONLY THIS BUTTON WILL DANCE & RESPOND TO THE 'is-checked' RHYTHM -->
        <!-- COULD IT BE THAT YOU WANT ONLY ONE CHECKED BUTTON WITHIN THE LOOP? -->
        <!-- WELL; LETS TRY THAT APPROACH AND SEE WHAT WE'D GET... -->
        <!-- ...BY THE WAY, IF YOU EXPLICITLY NEED THE BUTTON BELOW, PLEASE UNCOMMENT IT... -->
        <!-- <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="">All</button> -->

        <?php
            $term_id        = 69;
            $taxonomy_name  = 'project_category';
            $term_children  = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );
            // LET'S FIND OUT THE LENGTH OF THE ARRAY SO WE CAN GENERATE A RANDOM NUMBER WITHIN IT'S RANGE
            $iLength        = count($term_children);
            // NOW WE GENERATE A RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 0 AND $iLength MINUS 1: ($iLength - 1)
            $iRandNum       = rand(0, ($iLength - 1));
            // SO, NOW WE HAVE AN ARBITRARY TARGET INDEX (NUMERIC ARRAY KEY)....
            // THEN WE JUST MODIFY OUR foreach LOOP BY JUST ADDING THE ITERATION INDEX: $key=>
            // AFTERWARDS; WE USE THIS $key TO MATCH OUR $iRandNum AND THEN
            // SET THE ELEMENT AT THAT INDEX  TO HAVE THE is-checked CLASS...
            foreach ( $term_children as $key=>$child ) {
                // WE DO OUR CHECK & CREATE THE CLASS ON THE FLY HERE USING TERNARY COMPARISON:
                $sClass     = ($iRandNum == $key) ? "is-checked" : "";
                $term       = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );
                if( $term->count > 0 ) {
                    // WE JUST ADD THE CLASS ABOVE TO THE BUTTON.....
                    echo "<button class='button {$sClass}' data-filter='{$term->slug}'>{$term->name}</button>";
                };
            };
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Poiz !  I think I was a bit unclear - sorry for that!  I think you did understand most of what I need.  I added comments above that hopefully clear things up some.  I do need ALL as an option (just not with class is checked) that is easy enough but I want a specific option on the page to already be selected upon entry to the page (not all of them) I also posted a link as that will probably make more sense.